# How to modify core when there is no hook?

Tags: filters, comments, hooks, comment-form, core-modifications

I want to add a custom HTML5 attribute to the `<form>` element in the comments form. Since the form field itself is generated by `comment_form()`, and there is no hook to edit within the opening `<form>`, I'm not exactly sure how to do this? I don't need to replace the entire `comment_form()` function-- I just want to add a custom attribute to `<form>`, so that it has something like `<form ... data-my-custom="my_value">`. Tips, tricks, suggestions?

I'm running the latest version of WP (it auto-updates now! wahoo!).

Comment: You can always us jQuery if it's not possible with hooks.

Comment: Hi,What exactly you want because there many hooks and filters available for comment form. Please clarify

Comment: If you want to add a data attribute to the form tag itself when the form opens, it doesn't look like core allows for you to edit this with arguments for comment_form(). I'd say it might be easiest as Robert Hue suggested to just go the JS route to add the data attribute. You can see why it'd be difficult to overwrite that part in PHP if you look at comment-template.php in wp-includes, line 2187's function for comment_form. The comments above the function tell you what can be changed via hooks.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that [`comment_form`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/) hardcodes the `<form>` tag, so you cannot modify it with a filter or action. Adding your custom attribute with jquery would be possible, but then it wouldn't be in the source code and hence not be picked up by search engines you might be targeting. The alternative is to [buffer the entire output of the function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and do a search and replace there. Like this:

```
ob_start ('wpse193237_add_attribute_to_form');
comment_form();
ob_end_flush();

function wpse193237_add_attribute_to_form ($buffer) {
  return (str_replace ('<form', '<form data-my-custom="my_value"', $buffer));
  }
```